# convert xml data from 1 tag to 2 different column with xslt

Tags: xslt

I have

```
<datetime xml:space="preserve">2020-08-11T04:00:00</datetime>
```

I want to change this to

```
2020-08-11
04:00:00
```

with xslt, But I couldn't figure it out, I searched a lot but found nothing

Comment: This is trivial using `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`.

Comment: Thanks So much, This is it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, you can use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` using the T as reference to split up the text, like:

```
    <xsl:template match="datetime">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., 'T')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'T')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```